# Using the Possessive with Gerunds: appreciate their thinking or appreciate them thinking?

Tags: possessives, gerunds, syntactic-analysis

In formal writing, which sentence would be a better choice to imply "I appreciated that they had thought of me"?

1. I appreciated their thinking of me.
2. I appreciated them thinking of me.

Is there a subtle difference in the two constructions? To mean that sentence number 1 stresses on the act of thinking and sentence number 2 stresses on the people who are thinking? Or can both be used to mean the same thing?

Comment: Don't stress yourself with overthinking on this one. Both versions are in common use, and mean exactly the same. It's just different syntax.

Comment: The first is a gerund with a possessive pronoun; the second is a participial clause. As FumbleFingers said, they are interchangeable.

Comment: The syntax: "Their thinking of me" is ambiguous. If say, the adjective "constant" was added, then "thinking"  would be a noun and  "their constant thinking of me" a noun phrase.. But if the adverb "constantly" was added, "thinking" could only be a verb so "their constantly thinking of me" would be a gerund-participial clause. Your other example can only be a clause since there's no possibility of modifying "thinking" with an adjective.

Comment: 'I don't like his singing' and 'I don't like him singing' are not always interchangeable, for the reason you give. 'His speech is very pleasant, but I don't like **his** singing' where the nouny version is required, but 'He should be at home with that sore throat – I don't like/want **him** singing', where the more verby (ACC-ing) construction is easily the better choice. But this has been covered here before.